# Firebase rules to allow some user access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image]
I would like **only** user2, user3 to view user1's info from DB and **not** user 4.

I know I need to do something in the JSON rules:

**THE UIDUser2, UIDUser3** Would be replaced with the actual ID's when User1 allowed permission via the app.

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This is **my edit so far:**

```
 {
      "rules": {
    "Users":{
         "UIDHERE":{
                   ".read": auth.uid ==??
                   }
              }
      }

    }
```

How do I finish the rule? I want to retrieve the key's from the `Allowed` area to here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want only users whose ids are in `Allowed` node read other users information. Right?

If so... Here is rules for it.

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "root.child('Users/Allowed/'+auth.uid).exists()"
  }
}
```

**[UPDATED]**

`$uid` is an example of $ variables (you can give it different name but it must start with $) which dynamically gets the value of key under `Users` location.

**For example**: The rule what I have given you only allows users under `Allowed` node to read other users info, But it will block user to read his own information if this user is not in `Allowed` node.
If you want to add this too you need to change your rules like this.

```
"Users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid == auth.id || root.child('Users/Allowed/'+auth.uid).exists()"
  }
}
```

=========================================================================

In firebase rules there are [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) such as, `now`, `root`, `auth`, `data`, `newData` and [$ variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables).

> When you have a $location in your rules structure, you can use a
>   matching $ variable within your rule expression to get the name of the
>   actual child being read or written. So suppose we want to give every
>   user read and write access to their own /users/ location. We
>   could use:

Copied from firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location

If you want to know more about firebase security rules read the following section.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

## P.S.

Your structure is not so good. Data under `Users` node is jumbled. You should not have `Allowed` node on the same level as userIds. Instead it would be better if you either create new node (`allowedUsers`) at `Users` node level and move `Allowed` data there.

```
AllowedUsers
  - userid2
  - userid3
Users
  - userid1
  - userid2
  - userid3
  - userid4
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain some terminology? What does the "$uid$ mean?